# Nontrivial invariant transformations for heat equations

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

It is well known that if $u$ is a harmonic function on $\mathbb R^2$ then its Kelvin transform defined by
$$ v(r,\theta) = u(\frac{1}{r},\theta)$$
is also harmonic for $r>0$. Note that the Kelvin transform is defined in all dimensions but I stated it in dimension two for simplicity.

My question is whether something similar can be done for the heat equation
$$ \partial_t u - \Delta u =0,$$
that is to say, find a transformation $\psi: \mathbb R^{1+n} \to \mathbb R^{1+n}$ so that if $u$ solves heat equation then so does $u\circ \psi$. Of course, I don't want the trivial transformations like the parabolic scaling $\psi(t,x) = (\alpha^2 t, \alpha x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least when $n=1$, there are no nontrivial transformations of this kind.

Indeed, suppose that $v(t,x)=u(\tau(t,x),\xi(t,x))$, where $u_t=u_{xx}$. Then $u_{tx}=u_{xxx}$ and $u_{tt}=u_{xxxx}$, so that the equation
\begin{equation*}
    v_t=v_{xx} \tag{1}\label{1} 
\end{equation*}
can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
    \xi_x(u_{xxx}\tau_x+u_{xx}\xi_x)
+\tau_x\,(u_{xxxx}\tau_x+u_{xxx}\xi_x) \\ 
+u_{xx}\tau_{xx}+u_x\xi_{xx}-u_{xx}\tau_t-u_x\xi_t=0. \tag{2}\label{2} 
\end{equation*}
Since at any point $(t,x)$ the partial derivatives $u_x,u_{xx},u_{xx},u_{xxx},u_{xxxx}$ can take arbitrary real values, the coefficients of $u_x,u_{xx},u_{xx},u_{xxx},u_{xxxx}$ in \eqref{2} must all be zero. In particular, the coefficient $\tau_x^2$ of $u_{xxxx}$ in \eqref{2} must be $0$, so that $\tau_x=\tau_{xx}=0$, and we can write $\tau(t,x)=T(t)$ for some function $T$.

So, \eqref{2} implies
\begin{equation*}
    u_{xx}(\xi_x^2-T'(t))+u_x(\xi_{xx}-\xi_t)=0,
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    \xi_x^2=T'(t),\quad\xi_{xx}=\xi_t. 
\end{equation*}
Hence, $\xi_x\xi_{xx}=0$ and, if $\xi$ is real analytic, then
\begin{equation*}
\xi_{xx}=0, \quad\text{whence}\quad\xi_t=0, 
\end{equation*}
whence for some real $a,b,c$ we have $\xi(t,x)=a+bx$, $T'(t)=\xi_x^2=b^2$, $\tau(t,x)=T(t)=c+b^2t$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    \xi(t,x)=a+bx,\quad\tau(t,x)=c+b^2t.
\end{equation*}

The case $n\ge2$ should be similar.

Comment: I was aware of the fact that in one dimensions this does not work but still thought there may be a chance in higher dimensions. Perhaps you are right.

Comment: @Ali : If I knew that you had known about the $n=1$ case, I'd probably not write this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, how about the Appell transform, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993650).

$$v(t,x)\mapsto\Gamma(t,x)v(-\frac1t,\frac xt)$$
where $\Gamma$ is the heat kernel.

Truly nontrivial if you ask me. Of course, this inverts time and not space!

Comment: But this transformation uses, not only composition, but also multiplication.

Comment: Kelvin transform in higher dimensions also involves a multiplication (with the fundamental solution).